# Reputation points showing as minus two in my summary instead of plus two as in the question

Tags: support, reputation

Small point but I earned two reputations points for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712043/email-address-validation-using-asp-net-mvc-data-type-attributes/18283135#18283135) but it shows as -2 in my summary. Am I missing something?

Comment: You didn't earn reputation. You were downvoted on April 14th, as the timeline shows as well http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16712043/timeline

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has been upvoted 3 times and downvoted once.  That's a net reputation change of +28.  The current *score* of the post is +2.

Only the downvote happened recently.  That has resulted in a -2 net reputation change *on the day represented in the summary alone*, rather than throughout the posts entire history.